# How to modally present a navigation controller in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I am trying to present a navigation controller modally,the thing is my navigation bar  is not showing any baritems... any ideas? This is my code. If I add a backgroud color to the navigation bar it actually shows, but not the buttons... Please help!

```
if let navigationController = baseController as? UINavigationController {
    if UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        navigationController.present(webViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let webNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: webViewController)
        webNavigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelTapped))
        webNavigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        webNavigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        navigationController.present(webNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
webNavigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(...
```

It is not `webNavigationController` whose `navigationItem` dictates the presence of bar button items, but rather `webViewController`.

Comment: Woooow... You just saved my life mate, it was such a simple thing...Thanks a lot!! I mean it, I had been trying for hours!